# Input not saving to database, remains null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

## The Suspected Problem

I am trying to allow for the body of the blog to be submitted and output with html. An error is not provided, however anything submitted for `PageBody`,`PublishDateUTC`,`CreateDateUTC`, or `ModifyDateUTC` is not saved to the database. What can I change to allow the view to create, read, update, and delete this column record?

Found in `Article.cs` (Model)

```
[AllowHtml]
public string PageBody { get; set; }
```

Found in `ArticleController.cs` (Controller)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,PublishDate,CreateDate,ModifyDate,Author,PageBody,Feature,Published,Excerpt,PublishDateUTC,CreateDateUTC,ModifyDateUTC,CanonicalUrl,UrlSlug,Category,Tag")] ArticleContent articles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Articles.Add(articles);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(articles);
    }
//Omitted
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,PublishDate,CreateDate,ModifyDate,Author,PageBody,Feature,Published,Excerpt,PublishDateUTC,CreateDateUTC,ModifyDateUTC,CanonicalUrl,UrlSlug,Category,Tag")] ArticleContent articles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(articles).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(articles);
    }
```

Found in `Edit.cshtml` (View)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageBody, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "PageBody"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageBody, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### Article.cs (Model)

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JosephMCasey.Areas.Article.Models
{
    public class ArticleContent
    {
        [Key]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(256, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Title cannot be longer than 256 characters.")]
        public string Title { get; set;}
        [Display(Name = "Create Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Publish Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PublishDate { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Modify Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string PageBody { get; set; }
        public string Feature { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
        public string Excerpt { get; set;}
        [Display(Name = "UTC of Create Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? CreateDateUTC { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "UTC of Publish Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? PublishDateUTC { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "GMT of Modify Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? ModifyDateUTC { get; set; }
        public string CanonicalUrl { get; set; }
        public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
    public class ArticleDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ArticleContent> Articles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

### ArticleController.cs (Controller)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using JosephMCasey.Areas.Article.Models;

namespace JosephMCasey.Areas.Article.Controllers
{
    public class ArticlesController : Controller
    {
        private ArticleDBContext db = new ArticleDBContext();

        // GET: Article/Articles
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Articles.ToList());
        }
        // GET: Article/Articles/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ArticleContent articles = db.Articles.Find(id);
            if (articles == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(articles);
        }

        // GET: Article/Articles/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Article/Articles/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,PublishDate,CreateDate,ModifyDate,Author,PageBody,Feature,Published,Excerpt,PublishDateUTC,CreateDateUTC,ModifyDateUTC,CanonicalUrl,UrlSlug,Category,Tag")] ArticleContent articles)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Articles.Add(articles);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(articles);
        }

        // GET: Article/Articles/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ArticleContent articles = db.Articles.Find(id);
            if (articles == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(articles);
        }

        // POST: Article/Articles/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PostId,Title,PublishDate,CreateDate,ModifyDate,Author,PageBody,Feature,Published,Excerpt,PublishDateUTC,CreateDateUTC,ModifyDateUTC,CanonicalUrl,UrlSlug,Category,Tag")] ArticleContent articles)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(articles).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(articles);
        }

        // GET: Article/Articles/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            ArticleContent articles = db.Articles.Find(id);
            if (articles == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(articles);
        }

        // POST: Article/Articles/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            ArticleContent articles = db.Articles.Find(id);
            db.Articles.Remove(articles);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit.cshtml (View)

```
@model JosephMCasey.Areas.Article.Models.ArticleContent

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<section class="bg-ocean light row text-center shelve">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h2>Edit Articles</h2>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PostId)

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublishDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublishDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifyDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifyDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifyDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PageBody, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PageBody, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "PageBody"} })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PageBody, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Feature, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Feature, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Feature, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Published, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Published)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Published, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Excerpt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Excerpt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Excerpt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublishDateUTC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublishDateUTC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishDateUTC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDateUTC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDateUTC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDateUTC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModifyDateUTC, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModifyDateUTC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModifyDateUTC, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CanonicalUrl, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CanonicalUrl, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CanonicalUrl, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UrlSlug, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UrlSlug, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UrlSlug, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Category, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 border border-light">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tag, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
        @section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }
```

---

### What I thought would fix it

I thought that the following would fix it

- Build Solution
- Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName JosephMCasey.Areas.Article.Models.ArticleDBContext (Already Enabled, Doy!)
- Add-Migration ModifyBlogAttributes (Wait I'm not suppose to do that)
- Update-Database -TargetMigration ModifyBlogAttributes (ok, this is what I need to do)
- Run Application Nothing

Comment: Not 100% sure but I do have some recollection of that if you want to set Id and Name by the HtmlAttributes they should all start with a capital letter, i.e. @Id = "PageBody", tried that?

Comment: @JFM, It's not the Id.

Comment: I dont think you need to set the id at all really, it should be automatically set by the EditorFor. Anyway, when you step through the Create method, I guess you get the PageBody set but it doesnt get persisted by EF?

Comment: The ID was manually set for the CKEditor to be called reliably.

When I use the create method, it's almost as if it validates, skips the first action [db.Articles.Add(articles);] then completes the next two actions [db.SaveChanges(); return RedirectToAction("Index");].